# Enforce uniqueness between two one-to-one tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, foreign-keys, unique-constraint

I have two tables which have a one-to-one relationship with each other and the second table primary key references the first tables primary key.  Records need to be unique for a given column in each of the tables.  For instance, if I changed my schema to combine the two tables into one, it would be something like `UNIQUE INDEX my_unique_index (column1 ASC, column2 ASC)`.

It is my understanding that I cannot use a unique index between two tables.  Maybe a trigger?

How can I obtain this functionality when using two tables with a one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Tables don't share primary keys.  If you need this functionality, then you have one table with a primary key that the other tables refer to.  This is tricky to set up in MySQL . . . you might need a trigger for all the constraints.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Sorry for the confusion.  Yes, I have one table with a PK that the other table refers to.  How could this be implemented?  Insert record in table1.  Insert record in table2, and use trigger to indicate error?  Then use roleback to delete both?

Answer (score 0):

only way you can do it is trigger. before each insert/update from each table you will need to make sure it does not break the uniqueness constraint you want to keep.

Comment: Trigger will work for the second insert, but how do I then delete the record in the first insert?

Comment: what do you mean? each time you do an insert, you check that it does not violate the uniqueness across the tables, if it does you fail it.

Comment: I have two tables.  The constrain is based on a column in each of the two tables.  I insert a record in the first table.  I then insert a record in the second table, and the trigger looks at the column value in the first table as well as the second table which is being inserted, and checks if it is duplicated.  If duplicated, it throws an error or whatever and doesn't insert.  I still have the record in the first table which is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Is an AUTO_INCREMENT involved?  If so, see `LAST_INSERT_ID()` -- `INSERT` into one table without specifying the AI, then use that function to get the id.  Then insert into the other table.

No AI?  You *do* have the PK?  Then, simply do two separate INSERTs.

Yes, you probably want to use a BEGIN...COMMIT around the pair of INSERTs.

Comment: No AUTO_INCREMENT.  Sounds like it needs to be handled by the application?

Comment: Please describe a sequence of events where the uniqueness is violated.